# How to have only hour, minutes, and seconds for x-axis in matplotlib (and not the date)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have some parameters that I am plotting against 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex' as x-axis.
When I plot, I see the day and hour, minute, seconds. How do I get rid of the day? 
Here is a minimal form of the problem:

```
time_ci=
DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-12 13:25:00', '2019-07-12 13:25:10',
           '2019-07-12 13:25:20', '2019-07-12 13:25:30',
           '2019-07-12 13:25:40', '2019-07-12 13:25:50'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)



 h2o_g_= masked_array(
data=[[1.7723087072372437],
    [1.7723088264465332],
    [1.7723087072372437],
    [1.7723088264465332],
    [1.7723089456558228],
    [1.7723088264465332]],
mask=[[False],
    [False],
    [False],
    [False],
    [False],
    [False]],
fill_value=1e+20,
dtype=float32)
```

This is the script for the plot:

```
fig2, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))
plt.plot(time_ci,h2o_g)
```

This is what I get:

[image: The plot with datetime, the 12 is the date and i do not want it there.]

The 12 is the date (that I don't want to be there).

I have already tried these methods:

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
ax=plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

and also:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
h_fmt = mdates.IndexDateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
```

but none of them worked.

Also, the seconds are not there either.

Comment: The first attempt works. (The second will probably not work though) Can you provide a [mcve] and show the problem you face?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added the minimal example and the first attempt I don't get an error but doesn't work either.

Comment: What is `h2o_g = data=[` supposed to do?

Comment: It was a mistake, i erased the "masked_array(data=" from the beginning of the piece of code I posted.

Comment: Would it be possible to show a single piece of copy-pastable code???

Comment: You may also be interested in https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html which tries to do this sort of thing automatically

Comment: Anyways the `DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')` approach works as expected. The output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXUjJ.png).

Comment: It works in this short example, but not with my full arrays. Could it have to do with the fact that my arrays are masked arrays?

Comment: Some ideas:
1- Convert your timestamp into string using str
2- Create an additional column with strings with only hour, minute, second
3- Then overwrite the x axis with set_xticks or xticks with this additional column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prefect way, but I removed the date part(left the time part only) and converted into seconds by using these:

```
# Calculate total-seconds of difference
df["total_seconds"] = [x.total_seconds() for x in df['time']]

# df['hms'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time_ns'],format="%H:%M:%S")
df['hms'] = pd.Series([x.time() for x in df['start_time_ns']])
```

This is the graph that I plotted, hope it helps :

[image]